# Select que retorne JSON

Tags: php, json, select

Olá!
tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

## login.php

```
<?php 
    $msg;
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {
        $login = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['login']);
        $senha = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['senha']);

        if (strlen($login)<4 || strlen($login)>50) {
            $msg = array('status' => 0, 'msg' => "Login deve ter entre 4 a 50 caracteres!" );
        }elseif (strlen($senha)<8 || strlen($senha)>20) {
            $msg = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=> "Senha deve ter entre 8 a 20 caracteres");
        }else{
            require_once("logar.php");
        }
    }else{
        $msg = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=>"Informe o Usuario e Senha!");
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
 ?>
```

## logar.php

```
<?php 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    include "conexao.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuemail='$login' AND ususenha = MD5('$senha')";
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conexao->query($sql));
    if ($resultado) {
        
        $msg = array('status' =>1 , 'user' =>$resultado);

    }else{
        $msg = array('status' =>2 , 'msg' => "Usuario informado não existe!" );
    }
    

 ?>
```

na cunsulta do banco ta certo, mais estou testando ele no ADVENCED REST CLIENT e só retorna que  o usuario não existe. Alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Cadê o `json_encode()` no segundo código?

Comment: o login.php já faz isso..  Ele acessa o logar.php e oega de lá.

Answer (score 0):

Você está verificando se uma variável do tipo array é verdadeira :/, na verdade você tem que verificar se ela está vazia ou se retornou um usuário.

```
$row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row > 0){
   //....
}
```

ou

```
if($row == 1){
  //....
}
```

Comment: valeu.. resolvi aqui... o erro foi no campo senha do banco estava varchar(20), como a senha está em md5 não salvava todos os caracteres, salvava apenas 20 a´nunca dava certo a senha... Mais obrigado pela disposição em ajudar..